# SQLAlchemy - Return Generated Keys for INSERT?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am messing around with plain text SQL in SQLAlchemy. I'd prefer not to use ORM unless that is the only way to do this, but is there a way I can return the generated primary key value for a new record when I do an INSERT? Java's JDBC utility does this, and I'd be a bit surprised if there is not a way to do this with SQLAlchemy...

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///rexon_metals.db')
conn = engine.connect()

# I want this to return the generated primary key values
def insert_new_customer(customer_name, region, street_address, city, state, zip_code):
    stmt = text("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (NAME, REGION, STREET_ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP) VALUES ("
                ":customer_name, :region, :street_address, :city, :state, :zip_code)")

    return conn.execute(stmt, customer_name=customer_name, region=region, street_address=street_address, city=city, state=state, zip_code=zip_code)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it from [`.lastrowid`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#lastrowid):

```
result = insert_new_customer(...)
result.lastrowid
```

Comment: This has two problems. (1) What if another insert is taking place to same table in parallel? The value doesn't seem to be reliable. (2) What happens for bulk inserts? How do we get all the keys for all the rows?

Answer (score 13):

Maybe because it has been more than a year since the accepted answer, the answer did not solve the issue. So, I dug a little deeper into the docs of sqlalchemy and found [.inserted_primary_key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key). It returns a tuple of the **primary key** of the single inserted row using the `connection.execute()` command.

Edit: Another reason to use [.inserted_primary_key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key) instead of [.lastrowid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.lastrowid):

[.lastrowid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.lastrowid) is **database specific**, it may work for some databases while not for others. But [.inserted_primary_key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key) will **always work regardless of the underlying database**.

Comment: It is not working for me in the given scenario. It works with an insert() expression but not with `conn.execute(text(sql_code))`. So I go back to the psycopg2 module to get the "returning id".